# Select string split from table and then order by it - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

for example my table contains something like:

| id | name | price | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FRUIT:BANANA | 12$ | 13$ |
| 2 | BANANA | 15$ | 14$ |
| 3 | CUCAMBER | 5$ | 2$ |
| 4 | PLASTIC:UMBRELLA | 20$ | 5$ |
| 5 | PLASTIC:TABLE | 10$ | 50$ |
| 6 | TABLE | 12$ | 20$ |

as you can see, some of my names contains ":" in the middle, when I make select query I want the result will contain:

| id | name | price | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BANANA | 12$ | 13$ |
| 2 | BANANA | 15$ | 14$ |
| 3 | CUCAMBER | 5$ | 2$ |
| 4 | UMBRELLA | 20$ | 5$ |
| 5 | TABLE | 10$ | 50$ |
| 6 | TABLE | 12$ | 20$ |

I found some function that called STRING_SPLIT, but it works only if I from is after "FROM", not found function that I can use in SELECT.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: Don't store numbers as formatted string like with $-signs appended. You cannot calculate on that. Use an appropriate number type.

Comment: @stickybit unfortunately this is how I got the information from the API.

Comment: @stickybit and the request is to save the data "AS IS" it came from the API.
my problem is on PULLING.

Comment: Then consider transforming it, when inserting it into the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract the part of the `name` after the `:` (if it exists):

```
SELECT id, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ':', -1) name,
       price,
       cost
FROM tablename
ORDER BY name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0e4457c945bc3cbb0951e81b9454424).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX() function can solve your problem. [See the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ':', -1) AS name,
    price,
    cost
FROM
    your_table
```